# Memory leak in express.js when querying a database

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, sequelize.js

I'm currently struggling with a memory leak in express.js. By commenting the rest of the code out, I managed to narrow down to the following:

```
const db = require("../models")

class AuthorizationService {

    constructor(app) {
        this.db = db(app)
    }

    async retrieveRealmByDeviceId(req) {
        await this.db.Device.find({
            where: {
                id: "1"
            }
        })
    }
}

module.exports = AuthorizationService
```

The given code is not as the original, but as it is it still causes a leak. I'm also new to express.js and struggling with the code structure, as this is a project with legacy code.

The `../models` folder contains a bunch of models defined using Sequelize, such as the following:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const Device = sequelize.define("device", {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        userIdentifier: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    })

    Device.associate = (models) => {
        Device.hasMany(models.AuthenticationChallenge, {
            as: "ACS",
            foreignKey: "deviceId",
            sourceKey: "id",
            onDelete: "cascade"
        })
        Device.hasMany(models.DeviceCertificate, {
            as: "DCS",
            foreignKey: "deviceId",
            sourceKey: "id"
        })
        Device.belongsTo(models.Realm, {
            foreignKey: "realmId",
            targetKey: "id"
        })
        Device.belongsToMany(models.Certificate, {
            as: "CS",
            through: models.DeviceCertificate,
            foreignKey: "deviceId",
            otherKey: "certificateId",
            constraints: false
        })
    }

    return Device
}
```

I'm not sure what other info might be required, but please do let me know.

What could be causing this leak? How can I detect it?

Edit:

We just found out how to solve the leak, by introducing:

```
await this.db.sequelize.close()
```

As per the documentation, [close](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-close): "Close all connections used by this sequelize instance, and **free all references so the instance can be garbage collected**."

However, it appears that this choice was made by design to keep the DB connection up, possibly for performance reasons. Should we expect some sort of bottlenecks or other database performance issues if we manage the connections in this way? Or should we keep a connection for the duration of the request? In short, what's the proper way to manage connections in express.js?

Comment: I never liked this `this.db = require("../models")(app)` ... oh sure it's just passing a reference of app... but it never feels like that.  Anyways, how about putting `const db = require("../models")` at the top and then `this.db = db(app)`; ?

Comment: Is `this.db` ever getting cleaned up?

Comment: @CodyG., please see me update! The leak still holds.

Comment: @jfriend00 how could I do that?

Comment: Managing your connections probably depends on your db server hardware and db type (postgres, ms sql...)  but also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

Comment: It looks like every time you create an `AuthorizationService` object, you redefine your models.  How often are you doing that?